# How to modify a function to work recursively

Tags: r, function

This R function was written by someone else but I'm trying to modify it to work recursively. I've never dealt with creating/modifying R functions before and I'm a little lost.

The function is very similar to list.files except it creates a dataframe instead of a vector. The dataframe will have a column of the files full path and another column of just the name. Here is how the function is set up.

```
function(pathin = character, ext = '.ext'){
  if(length(grep(ext, pathin)) >= 1 ) {
    files<-data.frame(Path = pathin, 
                      Filename = gsub("(.*\\/)([^.]+)(\\.[[:alnum:]]+$)", "\\2", pathin), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  } else {
    files<-data.frame(Path = list.files(pathin, pattern = ext, full.names = TRUE), 
                      Filename = list.files(pathin, pattern = ext, full.names = FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
    files$Filename<-gsub(ext, "\\1", files$Filename)
  }
  files
}
```

I know that part of this will be modifying the `list.files` to have `recursive=TRUE` but that doesn't work entirely. Anyone have any suggestions or could point me towards some resources?

**EDIT:** I forgot to show an example of how this function works in a script.

```
files <- file_List(pathin = "C://Users//Public//Documents//", ext = ".ext")
```

Comment: If `recursive = TRUE` does not produce what you want, what exactly is your expected result? And I'm puzzled by your function definition: `function(pathin = character, etc.)` doesn't make much sense. Or is `character` a variable that you defined before?

Comment: @Stibu Great question! That's part of what I'm confused about. I did type `?character` into the console and it is a function apparently. 

Like I said, I didn't create this function. The expected results are a dataframe like I described in the question but instead of only looking in the specific directory, it will work recursively as well. I forgot to add an example of how the function works. I'll put that in an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The point is that I did use the function in this way using `recursive = TRUE` and it returned a data frame with files in the folder and the subfolders. So I wonder what else it was that you expected?

Comment: If you want to recurse down the directory tree, you'll need to give your function a name,  and then once you finish the `data.frame` work, make a "dir" or similar call and if there are subdirectories, then call your function recursively.